# How can i automate my test cases using test Microsoft Test Manager?

Tags: microsoft-test-manager

I am currently working on Microsoft Test Manager. We are not using MTM for any automation, what we do is just pass or fail the test cases manually. Please suggest me if there any possible way for start automating my test cases. If there is any mechanism for record and playing the test cases, that's what i want.

I am in search for getting a guideline to start the automation with the help of MTM. Can anyone help me to start this thing?

Answer (score 2):

This is two (or three) step process

- Creating Coded UI test as mentioned above. (Andrew)
   a. You have to create Coded UI project using VS ultimate version (I hope that you have it already) 
   b. Create your test (Eg EnvironmentCheck)
- Using automated code using the recorder (Generate code for Coded UI Test) or
- Using own code by have [TestMethod] attribute added on top of each test method  as follows

  ```
  [TestMethod]
  public void EnvironmentCheck()
  { 
     // your code here
  }
  ```

  More detail can be found on stack overflow question [Hand Coding Coded UI Tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17238253/hand-coding-coded-ui-tests) 
  c. Verify you can test your method with Visual studio ( Right click inside the method and Click 'Run Tests' or 'Debug Tests') 
   d. Then you submit your code to TFS Build server and build it successfully

  2. Create Test case at MTM (Microsoft Test Manager) 
     a. Create Test suite and new Test case at the mtm (as you did on manual test case) 
     b. New test case name can be 'EnvironmentCheck' and note down the ID (work ID) 
     c. Associate your work ID with test method using visual studio 
      
     More info [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd380741.aspx) 
     ==> This will make your test case to automated state at the mtm.
  3. (Create Lab environment or VMs - This is another process. [More on msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee518924.aspx)) 
     d. Create a test settings or lab setup  
     e. Execute the test by clicking Run or Run with options

This will be overall steps, but there will be more steps based on your what you want to automate test. You can refer more on book mentioned by Elena.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for are called coded UI tests. You start by creating an action recording of your manual test and then creating a coded UI test from that action recording. Do a google search for "coded UI" and you'll find lots of information.

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of *MSMD* articles describing this topic but if you want a guide here is a e-book to download for free that could help you to start:

[Testing for Continuous Delivery with Visual Studio 2012](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35380)

**PS:** If you are using *Visual Studio 2010* this book will be helpful, too, since the approach is similar.